# use the functions defined in the class

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, finite-group-theory

I'm writing a program for representation of finite groups and simple operations on their elements. I wrote most of the functionality which I need, for example inverse elements, generators, checking if subset is subgroup etc.

Unfortunately all my functions need identity element, set and operation. I want to define the appropriate instance of the class and use it instead of this trio. And here begins my problem, I don't quite know how to go about it and all I can find on the internet contains only examples of definitions, without usage examples.

Eventually I would like to work with groups `Sn`, so far I've tested my code on (`Zn +`).

I wrote this:

```
data Z2 = Elm Int deriving (Show, Eq)
z2 :: Int -> Z2
z2 a = Elm (a `mod` 2)

class FiniteGroup a where
    identity :: a
    op :: a -> a -> a -- operation
    set :: [a]

instance FiniteGroup Z2 where
    identity = (Elm 0)
    op (Elm x) (Elm y) = z2 (x+y)
    set = [(Elm 0), (Elm 1)]
```

And it works fine for the function `op`, for example:

```
*Main> (Elm 1) `op` (Elm 0)
Elm 1
```

Unfortunately, I cant use `identity` and `set`. How do I use it?

I also can't figure out how to refactor an existing function to use my type class.

For example I have this:

```
cyclicGenerators :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> (a -> a -> a) -> [a]
```

and it works fine, but I want to have something like this:

```
cyclicGenerators :: (Eq a) => FiniteGroup a -> [a]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cant use the identity and set, how to use it?

You must use them in a context which defines `a` unambiguously. E.g. providing an explicit type annotation

```
set :: [Z2]
identity :: Z2
```

Passing them to some function requiring a `Z2` also works. As long as the compiler can figure out which finite group you are talking about, you will be fine. Otherwise, you'll get an "ambiguous ..." error.

> How to replace signatures in function and again how to use identity and set in function which I've already defined.

Try e.g.

```
cyclicGenerators :: (Eq a, FiniteGroup a) => [a]
cyclicGenerators = filter isGenerator set
  where isGenerator x = ...  -- a Boolean telling whether it's a generator
```

Above the compiler "knows" that `set` refers to the finite group `a`, since we must return an `[a]` and `filter` doesn't change the type of the input list, hence the `set` must be of type `[a]` as well. Here type inference works very well in propagating types so that the correct finite group instance is selected.

---

Edit: the OP proposes the code

```
cyclicGenerators :: (FiniteGroup a) => [a]
cyclicGenerators = filter isGenerator set
        where isGenerator = (\x -> groupOrder set == elemOrder x)
```

which triggers an ambiguity error. Indeed, the last `set` is not forced to belong to the same group -- it would make sense to compare the group order of another group to the order of `x`. E.g. `groupOrder (set :: [Z5]) == elemOrder (identity :: [Z2])` would type check, since both are integers.

So we need to state that the type of that `set` is `[a]`. The plain Haskell way is

```
 where isGenerator = (\x -> groupOrder (set `asTypeOf` [x]) == elemOrder x)
```

where `asTypeOf` is a library function which simply returns its first argument, but requires it shares its type with the second argument. It is defined in the libraries as:

```
asTypeOf :: t -> t -> t
asTypeOf x y = x
```

Alternatively, we can exploit a very commonly used extension of GHC Haskell. First, we need to enable it by adding

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

at the *top* of the module file. Then, we can simply write

```
cyclicGenerators :: forall a . (FiniteGroup a) => [a]
                 -- ^^^^^^^^^^ added
cyclicGenerators = filter isGenerator set
        where isGenerator = (\x -> groupOrder (set :: [a]) == elemOrder x)
```

where we explicit state that `set` is of type `[a]`, so it belongs to the same group.

Comment: I wrote this: http://pastebin.com/hpDi9Ki9 and got it: http://pastebin.com/Ln99DYnQ

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot! Is there a place where I can read more about similar issues? Can you tell me what means "forall a ." ?

Comment: Basically, the universla quantifier `forall a .  ...` states that the caller can choose `a` to be whatever it wants. Note that, in this particular case, omitting `forall a .` does not change the type: the caller would be able to choose `a` anyway. However, GHC handles this redundant quantifier to mean "note the `a` as chosen by the caller -- if below I use `a` again, I'm referring to such chosen type` For the gory details you can read https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables